# Why differentiate, at a syntactic level, between interface and abstract class?

Tags: class, syntax, interface, language-design, abstract

(**DISCLAIMER**: This is NOT a question about understanding the difference between `abstract class`es and `interface`s. If you didn't get that, please read the title again. I am well-versed in the difference between a contract and a half-implemented subsystem.)

Let's take Java as just one example. It seems that there is little need for a distinct keyword `interface`, when from my point of view as a developer, the compiler spits out exactly the same thing, which in human-speak is, "You cannot utilise this until you derive (via `implements` or `extends`) a new class which implements its methods". Simple.

But there is one scenario which may prevent conflation of these two: When we need to `implement` more than one `interface`, since Java does not allow multiple inheritance (for `class`es). Surely it would be trivial to build the language in such a way that the compiler recognises when there are any method bodies or declared variables, and subsequently disallows multi-`implements`/`extends` where appropriate? Does order of precedence then present a problem?

Is this the only reason we have this syntactic differentiation?

P.S. One reason I ask this question is that this scenario can present quite a challenge in understanding for new OO programmers, and I think that handling this in a more streamlined fashion, at the language level, would greatly assist in more quickly grasping the conceptual differences.

Comment: Do you think " that the compiler recognises when there are any method bodies or or declared variables, and disallows multi-implements/extends where appropriate " would be simpler to understand than requiring explicitly declaring that difference? (I really don't.)

Comment: @Mat I take your point, yet I absolutely think it could be, if handled in the correct fashion. Others are free to suggest such a fashion.

Comment: Maybe it could be, maybe not, but it isn't. Not much point in asking why, unless you're asking Jim Gosling, which you aren't. One counter argument is that changing the thing that previously had no implementations to have them would invalidate all existing extending/implementing classes in a way that could now only be detected at runtime unless they were recompiled: not an attractive option. Whether that was Gosling's reason, or only reason, is anybody's guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Surely it would be trivial to build the language in such a way that the compiler recognises when there are any method bodies or declared variables, and subsequently disallows multi-implements/extends where appropriate?

Let's say you did do that. So your language lets you do this:

```
class Foo extends A, B, C {
}
```

And it doesn't complain as long as every method in `B` and `C` is abstract. Fine and dandy.

Now let's say that you didn't create `B`. It's in some other package someone else wrote. They don't know anything about your class `Foo`. When they made `B`, everything in it was abstract, but that was just a coincidence: they didn't happen to have anything concrete to put in there yet.

Later, they decide to add another method to `B`, which *is* concrete. Now, without realizing it, they've broken your class `Foo`.

One argument for having an explicit `interface` construct is that it makes the intent of the author of `B` clear to someone consuming it.

In general, I think your question is a good one. The language I work on, Dart, is actually close to what you're talking about: It has an explicit `interface` syntax now, but it's being removed in favor of pure abstract classes.

Comment: A sensible answer at last. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Even if none of A, B, or C ever included anything that would preclude it from being an interface, what should the parent type of `Foo` be.  How about the parent type of `Bar extends A, Foo, C, B`?

Comment: If A, B, and C were all completely abstract, the hypothetical language could use A or Object as the one concrete superclass. Either would work.